# Early 80s puppet sci fi with a princess and a fluffy guard dog

Tags: story-identification

I can't recall a lot but I'm pretty sure it was early 80s. All I remember is

- Puppets.
- A princess having been captured by an evil sorceress.
- A small round fluffy guard dog type creature that was the princess's pet.
- An army or a prince was sent to rescue her.

There was a super dramatic ending. It was definitely intergalactic because the princess was taken to a far off planet.

Comment: Was the princess of the porcine persuasion?  Did she lay about with karate chops when she got miffed?

Comment: lol no...I believe that was Miss Piggy, and she was a Muppet...not a Puppet.

Comment: What's that? A movie, a cartoon, a comic, a book...?

Comment: It was a TV show...it was similar to Thunderhawks in genre.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like *[X-Bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Bomber)* (called *Star Fleet* for English/American audiences).

One of the characters was Princess Lamia, who had a guard "dog" called Kirara.

[image: Princess Lamia and Kirara]

The title song of the English language version was later re-recorded and released as a single by Bryan May of Queen featuring Eddie Van Halen and some more of his friends.

Comment: My first thought was starfleet too. @Luky Bell does this http://www.jedisparadise.com/4/Star_Fleet_Story2.htm look familiar?

Comment: Eeek that is totally it omg omg omg thank you thank you thankyou...30ish year old mystery solved...I was beginning to think I'd imagined it. You guys are AWESOME 

Comment: Glad that answered it for you :) You can accept this as the answer by clicking the tick mark next to it. (Also, try and listen to the Bryan May version of the theme song, it's EPIC).